# Parsing Json string containing both json objects and arrays using gson

Tags: android

```
{
    "capmpaign_id": "<SomeText>",
    "start_time": "<Time In UTC Format>",
    "end_time": "<Time in UTC Format>",
    "song_directory": "<directory relative to sdcard root directory>",

    "song_list": [
        {"song_1.mp3": "<Time of play"},
        {"song_2.mp3": "<Time of play>"},
        {"song_3.mp3": "<Time of play>"}
    ],
    "time_ads":{
        "<audio file name>": "<Time to play>",
        "<audio file name>": "<Time to play>"
    },

    "location_ads":{
        "<audio file name>":{
            "lat": 29.0000,
            "long": 32.0987
        },
        "<audio file name>": {
            "lat": 143.6543,
            "long": 97.23
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is stored in a string. Then from that string anyone can parse it using gson.
I am working in android studio and am trying to parse it but it contains both json array and objects. I don't know how to parse both of them together using gson in android so could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you got to parse the string into a JsonObject:

```
JsonObject json = new JsonParser().parse(string).getAsJsonObject();
```

And then you simply can dig into that JsonObject by using `get` and `getAsJsonArray`,`getAsJsonObject`, `getAsString`, etc... For example:

```
String campaignId = json.get("capmpaign_id").getAsString();
JsonArray songList = json.get("song_list").getAsJsonArray();
JsonObject timeAds = json.get("time_ads").getAsJsonObject();
String audioFileName = timeAds.get("<audio file name>").getAsString();
```

Comment: i need to parse this with the help of GSON not json